# mysql query to find unique entries with multiple columns

Tags: mysql

When I have multiple columns, like a, b and c.
When I simply using SELECT DISTINCT c FROM 'tablename', it only shows column C.
I want to select entries that are unique and show all three rows.

```
 Not unique:
 a | b | c
 1 | 2 | 3
 1 | 4 | 5



Not unique:
a | b | c
1 | 2 | 3
0 | 2 | 3
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want only C to be distinct or all columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM t1 GROUP BY c
```

Note that by doing this some results may be discarded (i.e. the `1, 2, 3` row may be chosen or the `0, 2, 3` row may be chosen, but you can't be sure).  If that matters, you can use aggregation on the other columns such as via `GROUP_CONCAT`